# In Django when extending AbstractUser, how do you reorder admin fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-2.1

In a Django app I have a class that extends AbstractUser:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...more fields that are not in the parent...
```

When I look at the /admin/ I see that the parent fields are on top, and it looks really bad, with the password being the first field.  How do I put the child fields on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the fields by overriding UserAdmin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

@admin.register(User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (
            ('Personal information'),
            {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}
        )
    )
```

The above code will create a section called `Personal information` which will have the fields `first_name`, `last_name` and `email`.